# On command line, how to apply other context-menu operation on a file than default open?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, context-menu

With the `start` command in a Windows command line it is possible top apply the default context-menu "open" operation on a file, like:

```
start file.pdf
```

But the Windows context menu may define other operations than "open", for example an "Edit" or "Print" operation like shown below.

[image]

How to apply another context-menu operation to a file on the comment line, for example "Edit" or "Print"?

Comment: It should be possible. I don't have time to dig out the details right now but the operations and defaults are defined in the registry.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can choose whichever action you want from the command-line, you can change the default action though.

**Changing default filetype action**

I'll use PDF as an example.

At a Command Prompt type:

`assoc .pdf`

The command should return something similar to this:

`.pdf=AcroExch.Document.11`

[image]

Using the value above we can change the default action in the registry.

Open the registry and navigate to:

`HKLM\SOFTWARE\Classes\AcroExch.Document.11\shell`

Obviously switching out `AcroExch.Document.11` with the result from the previous command.

[image]

Change the `(Default)` value here to the desired default action. If you expand the `shell` key you should see the options available for the filetype.